# Erasing pairs of equal ranking in the same list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a function `erasing_pairs()` that should take a string and return a list r where all the pairs are removed.

Here's how the function is expected to look like:

```
def erasing_pairs(r):
    without_pairs=[]

    return without_pairs
```

So basically, I explained the desired outcome. Here's an attempt I made, but to no avail:

```
def erasing_pairs(r):
    without_pairs=[]
    without_pairs = [x for x in r if r.count((r[x][0])) == 1]
    return without_pairs
```

Comment: Per the posting guidelines, please post code that will reproduce the problem you describe.  The given code has quite a few indentation errors and various omissions.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.

Comment: I am very confused... your code blocks have a function called `erase_pair` but you say `erasing_pair` in your sentence, are they refering to the same function? Are you saying that `r` in your function represents a string? I'd expect your code to fail since doing `for x in r` would make `x` each character of the string `r` so `r[x]` would be quite invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make one small change to your data, for the sake of convenience. Instead of `10♠`, use `T♠`, This means you can compare the values by looking at the first character.

Sort first. This brings all potential pairs next to each other, for quick removal:

```
l.sort()
l.append([None]) # This helps check at the end of the list, 
                 # while avoiding accidentally reading beyond the end          
                 # of the list.
```

Then go through the list in pairs, adding any unpaired items to `without_pairs`.

```
without_pairs = []
i = 1
while i < len(r):
    if r[i-1][0] != r[i][0]:
        without_pairs.append(r[i-1])
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 2    
return without_pairs
```

Comment: Hello, I ran your function and it ends up giving an error. test is not defined. In fact, from where does testl come from?

Comment: NameError: name 'testl' is not defined.

Comment: Silly me, didn't completely change my variable names to yours. Now fixed (I hope)

Comment: If you want to keep 10 as 10, use `[:-1]` instead of `[0]`

Comment: I've changed how I deal with the end of the list. This should be better.

Comment: Perfect. Yes, It now displays the remaining elements looked for.